# Misunderstanding of Promise returns in a chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have a function that resamples a canvas image to a second canvas. As far as I understand it, by using `then`, it's using promises and is helping me obtain the delayed `return`, rather than getting something *undefined* if the `return` came too early.

```
function resample_sizeo(canvas, width, height) {

    // Initialize
    var resizer = sizeo();

    var canvasResampled = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvasResampled.width = width;
    canvasResampled.height = height;
    // Function using two canvas' in the form of: resize(from, to)
    return resizer.resize(canvas, canvasResampled)
    // Function that converts resampled canvas to a data blob
    .then(result => resizer.toBlob(result, 'image/jpeg', 95))
    // End with a blob to return
    .then(blob => blob);
}
```

I wish to chain together *n* amount of calls to `resample_sizeo` and run them sequentially. This is a popular request I see, and I also see that it's addressed well with `await/async` but I can't use these yet for reasons I won't go into here.

I got pretty close with using some scripts like [Promise-Waterfall](https://github.com/dotSlashLu/promise-waterfall/blob/master/index.js) but found my attempts to satisfy it's array of promise-returning functions were doubling my code and that - perhaps - I was going about this a long way if I already had a function that returned a promise. Maybe I was overcomplicating something simple and I had 90% of the work done. So I tried returning to my friend `then`. Surely if my function as already returning a promise, I could chain some calls to the function together?

```
resample_sizeo(sourceCanvas, widthsRequired[0], heightsRequired[0])
.then(function(result) { // (**)
    console.log(result);
    resampledImageBlobs[0] = result;
    resample_sizeo(sourceCanvas, widthsRequired[1], heightsRequired[1])
}).then(function(result) { // (***)
    resampledImageBlobs[1] = result;
    resample_sizeo(sourceCanvas, widthsRequired[2], heightsRequired[2])
}).then(function(result) {
    resampledImageBlobs[2] = result;
    resample_sizeo(sourceCanvas, widthsRequired[3], heightsRequired[3])
}).then(function(result) {
    resampledImageBlobs[3] = result;
    console.log("All done", resampledImageBlobs);
    uploadImageBlobSet(resampledImageBlobs, 'replace');
});
```

This didn't work. `resampledImageBlobs` shows that it's *[blob,undefined,undefined,undefined]* at the end, so it's not waiting for each function to finish before reaching the end. I've overlooked something. If I check the result of any of these calls individually, they return a blob. But they're not chaining sequentially and waiting in turn.

Comment: You have `return` the inner `resample_sizeo(…)` promises from the `then` callbacks, otherwise the next promise won't know what to wait for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from `resample_sizeo`. Otherwise your next call to `.then(...)` will run immediately, and the `result` argument will be the usual return value of a function, which is `undefined`:

```
resample_sizeo(sourceCanvas, widthsRequired[0], heightsRequired[0])
.then(function(result) { // (**)
    console.log(result);
    resampledImageBlobs[0] = result;
    return resample_sizeo(sourceCanvas, widthsRequired[1], heightsRequired[1])
}).then(function(result) { // (***)
    resampledImageBlobs[1] = result;
    return resample_sizeo(sourceCanvas, widthsRequired[2], heightsRequired[2])
}).then(function(result) {
    resampledImageBlobs[2] = result;
    return resample_sizeo(sourceCanvas, widthsRequired[3], heightsRequired[3])
}).then(function(result) {
    resampledImageBlobs[3] = result;
    console.log("All done", resampledImageBlobs);
    uploadImageBlobSet(resampledImageBlobs, 'replace');
});
```

Comment: Many thanks Frank! I've spent about 14hours trying various techniques am so glad I realised my original code was closer to the answer than all the rabbit holes of promises I went down. I'm still getting my head around promises and missed that a return was needed, like you mentioned. It seems obvious in context but I think my head was still jumbled.

Comment: @biscuitstack You're welcome, it's a common mistake :)